# Where is a good place to locate / source good script & story writers?

Tags: screenwriting, publisher, writer

I am working for a company that wishes to source writers for their current production of an upcoming funny cartoon series called Firsty.

The directors are currently looking for writers & stories for future episodes.
And are taking submissions online.

Not sure if this is the place to ask, but where is a good place to locate / source good script & story writers to who are interested in writing for an animated series?

Comment: Isn't this what agents are for? I think you look for an agency that specializes in this.

Comment: They are a small production company who wish to not use agencies and just deal with writers directly.   They want writers to submit their Scripts / Stories online so they can read over and choose best writers / stories themselves.

Comment: There should be several free lance websites you can go to where people are putting their work up for hire. For the purposes of the site, we can't market products/services however, I would look into that.

Comment: It frankly sounds like you are soliciting writers. I would encourage anyone who might be tempted to nibble your way, to be very careful. And, I encourage you to use an agency.

Comment: @DPT I did cringe at the idea with the way this was written...but I was definitely having the alarms go off in my head at the possible attempt of stealing work or hoping they find a writer who is not knowledgeable in contracts to take advantage of. However, I will repeat to sean that if he wants someone who is "free lance" there are plenty of websites out there with a quick google...

Comment: The company is legit. I don't want to come across spamy so I'm not mentioning the site.  They are not looking to rip off ideas or stories and they have 100's of stories & many people involved in production. its all about involving the world community in their projects hence the "Anyone can submit a story".   All writers will be credited if stories were to be made into episodes in the future.  ggiaquin your answer about freelancing writing sites is pretty much what i'm looking for. petty you can't name a few. I'll keep searching. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ghostwriter on [Reedsy.com](https://reedsy.com/ghostwriting/book-ghostwriter) may be what your looking for. It's at least a place to start your search.

Another avenue to explore would be to put up a webpage for submission on the company's website and call for script writers to submit directly. I would refrain from asking for ideas or stories directly (as mentioned in the comments, it can come off as a little fishy) and look more at sample pieces submitted to put together a team of screenplay writers that will convey the voice and tone of what your company is looking to produce.

Hope this helps.

Comment: They have a website with submission page and "and call for script writers to submit directly."  is pretty much exactly what im looking to do for them.  
  but I don't know which sites are best to do this on?    also they are not against looking for ghost writers, but all writers will get full credit unless requested otherwise.  I will check out reedsy.     Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

The [Writer's Guild of America](https://apps.wga.org/agency/Findwriter.aspx) is a possibility because professional screenwriters and their agents are members. They're very conscientious about fair contracts.